# How do I integrate groupby with query on?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am relative new to programming python so dont be to harsh on me please.

I have a large covid19 dataframe with data from each country each day.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2pbv.png)

I did query the date to just have 11.11.2020 to work with and dropped the row 56215 (cumulative data of the world).

[After the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkK4h.png)

Now I want to group by continents on the specific day to compare e.g. deaths per million with a plot. How do I do that?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

You should be able to do

```
covid19.groupby(['continent'])
```

Comment: Something like this is not working. A normal groupby is no problem but in connection with the covid19.query I am kind of lost.

covid19.query("date=='11/11/2020'").drop(56215).groupby(['continent'])